# while trying to cast to date getting error in hibernate native sql

Tags: hibernate

SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery("select * from open_bug_weekly_graph_project where rec_date::date = current_date  and project !=\'ALL\' order by project");
         List records1 = query1.list();

Comment: Please show description of open_bug_weekly_graph_project table. At least, what type is 'rec_date' column ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply  i got the solution     i just  change      where rec_date::date = current_date  to   where date(rec_date) = current_date                                                                     SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery("select * from open_bug_weekly_graph_project where date(rec_date) = current_date  and project !=\'ALL\' order by project");
         List<Object[]> records1 = query1.list();